# Trying to install Brave, "Curl: (23) Failure writting output to destination"

Tags: command-line, curl, brave

Just installed Ubuntu, I am a total newbie, I tried installing brave via the official installation instructions for installing Brave on Ubuntu (and Mint and Debian) here: https://brave.com/linux/

But things errored out on the second line.  I got to:

```
sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg
```

after installing curl, so really it is the first line having anything to do with Brave at all, and I immediately got a:

```
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
```

I have been looking around for pre-existing help on line with regards to "curl: (23)" type errors, and basically all the advice was to delete and then update curl by reinstalling it.  So I have done that a number of times in different ways now, but it doesn't do anything, I still have the same issue.

As an aside, which of the log files in the var/log directory are the logs written when installing Ubuntu.  A few little errors occurred on install and I want to get those logs to see if any of them need fixes or whatnot -- even to just figure out what happened didn't get installed would be nice.

Comment: Does the `/usr/share/keyrings/` directory exist?

Comment: ...oh ... it does not appear to I take it I have to make one and curl won't do that on its own?

There is a /usr/share/keyring/ directory (i.e. no "s" at the end of keyring) should I use that in the curl command instead, or is that for something else and I would be a crazy maniac to try that with the Brave installation and I should make the keyrings folder insead?

Comment: Tried doing the original using the singular "keyring" i.e.:

    sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyring/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg

because the usr/share/keyring folder does exist, but this attempt also gives the same "curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination" error

Comment: The output of `type -a curl` might help

Answer (score 0):

Apparently using:

```
curl
```

and specifying

```
/usr/bin/curl
```

are two different things, for reason my dumb n00b brain doesn't understand.  Replacing the original (and specified on the proper installation website):

```
sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg
```

with

```
sudo /usr/bin/curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg
```

I have no idea why that is necessary, or why that wasn't specified in the official instructions

Comment: I have checked the /etc/environment it seems to have the normal path listings according to what I am seeing on line so I have no idea why it is having me use snap curl instead of the most recent full version of curl that I installed (and then reinstalled a couple of times as that seemed to be the only advice I could find around for related problems posted on the net, but which never worked.)